# How to solve 'data binding is not enabled' error while using view binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-viewbinding

I am using view binding and to do so I used the following code.

```
buildFeatures{ viewBinding true }
```

And I got this error:

```
> [databinding] {"msg":"Found \u003clayout\u003e but data binding is not
> enabled.\n\nAdd buildFeatures.dataBinding \u003d true to your
> build.gradle to enable
> it.","file":"C:\\Users\\akash\\AndroidStudioProjects\\NavigationSafeArgs\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_home.xml","pos":[]}
```

After reading the thrown error I thought It is saying to enable `dataBinding` So I added `dataBinding true` too inside `buildFeatures`. Still It throws the same error.

Here is my fragment_home.xml code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="@string/home_screen"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login" />
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: View Binding and Data Binding are two different concepts. replace code with `buildFeatures{ dataBinding true }`

Comment: Even without dataBinding enabled, It throws the same error.

Comment: Can you post your fragment_home.xml?

Comment: @HenryTwist I have updated the question with fragment_home.xml code.

Comment: And can you post more of your build.gradle showing where you've enabled data binding?

Comment: I have enabled dataBinding inside buildFeatures alongwith viewBinding.

Comment: @AlphaOne I have enabled dataBinding and viewbinding both inside the buildFeatures.

Answer (score 29):

Enabling dataBinding and viewBinding together solved my problem.

```
 buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
 }
```

I also added kotlin-kapt into plugins

```
plugins {
     id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same problem. removing the tags `<layout>` and `</layout>` worked for me